# Is it OK for SEO to use a photo's tags in the img alt text when a caption isn't available?

Tags: seo, images, tags, alt-attribute

Is it OK with SEO to use page tags as image `alt` and `<image:caption`>?

Images we are using doesn't have any caption or title. They just have tags (some of them 15 tags).

We were even thinking about using these tags in URLs. (For now ID is in use)

What do you think is the best for SEO in our case?